# How to validate so that input emails is equal in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I want to make a user-registration form where I will have fields such first name, last name, email, re-email, and password.

So my question is how to validate so the input email and re-email is equal. I couldn't find some help when reading the documentation for validation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/validators/

I found this site when googled, but it seems Django has changed alot since 2006. Because `AlwaysMatchOtherField` doesn't exist in 1.4

Here's is the site
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/sep/02/django-tips-user-registration/

Comment: Do you want the user to enter their email twice and validate that they have done it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite your forms `clean` method to do [validate fields that rely on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

```
class MyForm(models.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        if cleaned_data['email'] != cleaned_data['re_email']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your emails don't match")
        return cleaned_data
```

With regard a registration form, you should use [`django-registration`](http://code.google.com/p/django-registration/)

Answer (score 0):

here is what I did following the example of https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py :

```
def clean_email2(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    email2 = self.cleaned_data.get("email2")
    if email and email != email2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "Your email address differs",
        )
    return email2
```

In order to prevent errors, it is very important to check that the email addresses are filled in.